# select record if multiple different fields

Tags: mysql

I have this statement to select a record if there is more than one with the "year" field, but I need to select the record only if the "year" field is distinct AND more than one, so 2011 and 2011 would work for the below statement but it can only be two or more DIFFERENT years like 2011 and 2012.

```
HAVING COUNT(thereturn.sales.event_year) > 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
HAVING COUNT(distinct thereturn.sales.event_year) > 1
```